# Erro ao definir retorno de função em Typescript usando contextApi em React

Tags: react, funções, typescript, tipagem

Estou começando a estudar Typescript junto ao React, porém me deparei com esse erro apresentado pelo Typescript ao tentar efetuar a tipagem do retorno desta função de Login. Alguem poderia me ajudar a entender porque está errado?

```
Type '({ email, password, }: { email: string; password: string; }) => Promise<"Acredito que você ainda não se cadastrou no sistema" | "Acho que você errou suas credencias" | undefined>' is not assignable to type '(callback: { email: string; password: string; }) => string | void'.
Type 'Promise<"Acredito que você ainda não se cadastrou no sistema" | "Acho que você errou suas credencias" | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'string | void'.
```

Type para o meu contexto:

```
type ProviderValues = {
  signed: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
  user: User | null;
  setSigned: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  Login: (callback: {email: string, password: string}) => void | string;
};
```

Função Login

```
  async function Login({
    email,
    password,
  }: {
    email: string;
    password: string;
  }) {
    if (!account) {
      return "Acredito que você ainda não se cadastrou no sistema";
    }

    if (account.email === email && account.password === password) {
      setUser({
        email: account.email,
        name: account.name,
      });
      setSigned(true);

      localStorage.setItem(
        "@App:user",
        JSON.stringify({ email: account.email, name: account.name })
      );
      localStorage.setItem("@App:token", randomString(50));
    } else {
      return "Acho que você errou suas credencias";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Tenta retornar alguma string caso a pessoa tenha conseguido se logar com sucesso. Pelo tipo que você declarou a função retorna "void" ou "string", mas do jeito que foi implementada ela está retornando "undefined" caso o usuário logue com sucesso.

Comment: @GustavoCesário acabei tentando essa forma, retornando uma string qualquer caso logue com sucesso, mas mesmo assim o erro persiste

Comment: `Login` é _async_ ou não? Voce colocou `async Login(...)`. Tente colocar um `return` no segundo `if`.

Comment: Consegui resolver  trocando a tipagem para Promise<string | void>, ficando assim o código:
`Login: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<string | void>;`

Mas não sei se era o ideal

Comment: @IgorAzevedo quando tu bota async na declaracão da funcão ela vai sempre retornar uma promise, no seu caso tu não precisa disso pois não é executado nada assinconamente na funcão login.